# Не тот тип поля Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-template

UPDATE:
Вопрос решен, создание полей надо было вынести из класса Meta

Создаю форму на Django, поле должно быть типа password, но в результате тип text

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth import models as mod


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = mod.User
        username = forms.CharField(label='Login', max_length=100)
        password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput())
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .forms import PostForm


# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    template = loader.get_template('form.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return HttpResponse(template.render({'form': form}, request))
```

HTML код:

```html
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" class="input">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Подтвердить</button>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Как модель используется django.contrib.auth.models.User

Comment: Поля должны быть прописаны не в Meta

Comment: Никто [документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) не читает.